# React: Why is element style not toggling with setState?

Tags: reactjs

It's just a simple toggle mechanism:

Onclick of the element is to toggle a border color change by responding to state change.  It changes the color once! But won't toggle back to original color.

(I've experimented with so many variations of the functionality, read/reread React docs on state, setState's asynchronous/batch change functionality, and combed SO again-and-again.)

Can someone help me find a solution?

Thanks in advance!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Button extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      active: false,
    }
    this.updateActive = this.updateActive.bind(this);
  }



 updateActive(){
    this.setState(function(){
      this.state.active = !this.state.active;
      { return this.state.active; }
    });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="seq_btn" onClick={this.updateActive} style={ {borderColor: this.state.active ? 'black' : 'rgb(193, 255, 112)' }}></div>
    )
  }
}

export default Button;
```

Comment: Both answers below are correct, don't forget to mark one of them as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your return syntax is incorrect:

```
this.setState(function(){
  this.state.active = !this.state.active;
  { return this.state.active; }
});
```

This should be:

```
this.setState(function(){
  return { active: !this.state.active };
});
```

However, you don't need to use the callback here at all. You should just setState with the new data.

```
this.setState({ active: !this.state.active });
```

Comment: Thanks, Andy!  Too, why does the key `active` *not* require the `this.state`?

Comment: The object you pass to `setState` is **merged** into the current component's state. You should only pass in state updates.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of good habit, you should *never* mutate state in any form that isn't directly performed with setState

Even using

```
this.state.active = !this.state.active
```

is bad form and is most likely your issue.

Instead consider

```
this.setState({ active: !this.state.active });
```

Also understand that setState's can be batched for processing later, they are not always immediately executed.

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

As noted below, a functional component would serve the same purpose without the overhead of lifecycle methods

```
import React from "react";

const Button = ({ active, clickAction }) => (
    <div onClick={clickAction} className={{ borderColor: active ? "green": "purple"}}>
</div>);

export default Button;
```

Comment: Thanks, Joshua!  Yea, I read the docs on asynchronous/batch state change.  So, I know this is a dangerous means of accomplishing what I want to accomplish.  What's the alternative?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with changing the state of a button like this, however if this component has a parent that contains other state affected by this "click" then I'd suggest passing the style for this Button down through props. There is seldom a good reason to make a component that only renders a button extend React Component when the same can be achieved through functional components without the overhead of lifecycle methods

Comment: Ah.  That's exactly what's going to happen.  How would I go about passing style as a prop?  `<Button style="'[color]'">`, then some style toggle functionality inside the Button component?

Comment: See the bottom of my answer for passing data through props. I edited it to include a functional button component. Although I used the "active" prop you used initially, you can replace it with color and just set border color based on what is passed.